# How to get httpOnly cookies from android.webkit.CookieManager

Tags: java, android, cookies, webkit

I need to know whether a cookie in the webkit browser is httpOnly or not.
Using the method getCookie(URL) only return a String with the cookies name and values.

I can get it from java.net.CookieManager easily, but I have no idea if it is possible to convert android.webkit.CookieManager to java.net.CookieManager.

**Update 1**
I gave up trying do that. My guess is that what I want to do is impossible.
I tried to Override the shouldInterceptRequest method to open a new connection using HttpUrlConnection and return a new WebResourceResponse with the ImputStream returned from HttpUrlConnection but, seems that the webview doesn't accept javascript after a call come from shouldInterceptRequest. :-(

Answer (score 2):

This can be done via reflection, e.g.:

```
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();

Field mChromeCookieManager = cookieManager.getClass().getDeclaredField("mChromeCookieManager");
mChromeCookieManager.setAccessible(true);

Object awCookieManager = mChromeCookieManager.get(cookieManager);

Method getCookie = awCookieManager.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("nativeGetCookie", String.class);
getCookie.setAccessible(true);

Object cookie = getCookie.invoke(awCookieManager, url);
```

(Tested on Android 5.1.1)

Comment: I've tried this, not working for me, is there something i've missed? Anyone else tried this and succeeded?

Comment: Probaby it's already broken, because that's what happens if you access private internals. Never do this.

Answer (score -3):

To isolate http-cookies, Inject `document.cookie` into the page it should return all non-http cookies to the JS interface callback. Then get the result of the `CookieManager` call. The extra cookies in the set are most likely httponly. Simple string work or a hash should do the trick! Works on Android 6 and 7 for me.

Comment: What do you mean "the" CookieManager call?  There is no call you can make (without reflection like in Armand's answer) that will return httponly cookies.  The question is about how to get them in the first place, not how to distinguish them if it were possible to get them.